# VirtualBox - Mounting raw NTFS partition seems to result in corruption

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ntfs

I am virtualizing Windows 7 using VirtualBox on a Ubuntu 11.10 host. Since I had some performance problems, I decided to mount my native Windows partition (I have a dual-boot setup) in raw mode, which worked pretty well and resulted in a significant performance improvement. Note that I don't actually boot the native Windows partition in VirtualBox, I just access my Documents folder.

However, after a couple of days, the VirtualBox image started running CHKDSK on boot, and found multiple errors on the disk (not bad sectors, just corrupted file indexes). When I booted my native Windows, some of my driver DLLs had a size of 0 bytes, and required a reinstall.

I am running this setup on my Thinkpad laptop, and I suspect that the corruption MAY be caused by the laptop going in suspend mode while the image was running (I never hibernated though). It just puzzles me that some of my driver DLLs, which are not touched by the VirtualBox image, got corrupted, and not any of my documents.

Has anyone experienced something like this with a similar setup, or do you have any ideas of what might have gone wrong? These are my specs:

```
VirtualBox 4.1.2
Ubuntu 10.11 (host)
Windows 7 Professional (guest)
Thinkpad T520
```

Comment: Did you run any filecheck mechanisms on the host? I don't know if it helps but you should update VirtualBox to the current version 4.1.8

Comment: After the VirtualBox image was done running CHKDSK, the native Windows instance also scanned the partition, and also found some lost files.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand what you mean with virtual box image. Are you saying your Ubuntu host did a filecheck on the windows files or not? Do you have write access from Ubuntu? Do you use NTFS-Filesystem for Windows? Do you mount the whole Windows system partition?